# Применение стилей к определенным элементам

Tags: css, css3

Есть 10 элементов в списке. 1, 2, n, ..., 10.
Необходимо разделить список так, чтобы стили применялись на: 1,2,5,6,9,10 элемент.
Другой стиль применялся на 3,4,7,8 элемент.
Есть ли способ сделать так? Выгрузка данных происходит на сервере, элементов может быть и 100, я написал к примеру от 1 до 10.

Comment: есть...`классы` или псевдокласс [`элемент:nth-child(odd | even | <число> | <выражение>) {...}`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/nth-child)

Comment: Мне не нужны классы, я бы хотел решение при помощи псевдокласса. Сейчас бы все классами завешать и жить себе спокойно. У меня выгрузка данных происходит с сервера.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам поможет `:nth-child()`

```css
#colored div:nth-child(1),
#colored div:nth-child(2),
#colored div:nth-child(4) {
    background-color: gray;
}

#colored div:nth-child(3),
#colored div:nth-child(6),
#colored div:nth-child(8) {
    background-color: wheat;
}

#colored div:nth-child(5),
#colored div:nth-child(7),
#colored div:nth-child(9) {
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div id="colored">
  <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div>
  <div>6</div><div>7</div><div>8</div><div>9</div>         
</div>
```

в котором можно еще и выражения задать:

```css
#colored div:nth-child(4n),
#colored div:nth-child(4n-1){
    background-color: red;
}

#colored div:nth-child(4n-2),
#colored div:nth-child(4n-3) {
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div id="colored">
  <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div>
  <div>6</div><div>7</div><div>8</div><div>9</div>         
</div>
```

Comment: У меня может быть их будет 20 или 30

Comment: @Zebren дополнил ответ

Comment: @Zebren я ссылку в коменты скинул...ntd-child может принимать выражение...осталось определить закономерность

Comment: Вот я и хочу понять, как сделать выражение так, чтобы 2 через 2 применялся класс, пока решения не нашел, решил обратиться сюда, может кто делал

Comment: @Zebren например 2 красных потом 2 зеленых?

Comment: Да, и так пока список не закончится

Comment: @Zebren изменил второй сниппет

Comment: 2 вариант походит, спасибо :)

Answer (score 0):

Если вопрос в описании закономерности, то условие (при нумерации с 1) может выглядеть так:

```
if ((idx - 1) % 4  < 2)  
    первый cтиль
else
  второй
```